# check if key and its value in exists in object

Tags: javascript, json, object

an object(i.e. request.query) must contain these keys and with keys they must have truthy values

```
const invoice_query_params = [
                'invoice_id',
                'invoice_receipt',
                'invoice_status',
                'payment_id',
                'signature' 
            ];
```

Comment: you can use Object.hasOwnProperty() here

Comment: yeah  i have done that part but also need to check for falsy value `invoice_query_params.every(param => req.query.hasOwnProperty(param)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function with the object as a parameter should check if that object contains every array element as a parameter and the value of it is not falsy.

```
const checkKeysAndValues = (yourObject) => invoice_query_params.every(param => yourObject.hasOwnProperty(param) && yourObject[param])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test hasOwnProperty and for truthy values of course this will exclude anything that evaluates as falsy and accept anything that evaluates as truthy.

```
const invoice_query_params = [
                'invoice_id',
                'invoice_receipt',
                'invoice_status',
                'payment_id',
                'signature' 
            ];
let ok = true; 
for(var i=0; i < invoice_query_params.lengh; i++){
  if (request.query.hasOwnProperty(invoice_query_params[i]){
     if(!request.query[invoice_query_param[i]]){
        ok = false; 
     } 
  }
}

if (ok){
  // all were truthy so do something.
}
```